# SVN does not appear to be reverting changes

Tags: svn, revert

I pulled from a repo, made changes across several files, and now I want to undo them.

I tried `svn revert -R .`, and `svn revert --depth infinity .` but when I call `svn status`, I'm still seeing all the files marked as modified, and they seem to be the same as they were before I tried to revert.

I saw [this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo) discussion in the docs on reverting changes, but it seems to deal with going from one commit to another, rather than undoing all uncommitted changes.

(I do not have access to TortoiseSVN.)

I can't give you an exact dump of the status command, but it looks somewhat like this:

```
>>svn status
?    dir/
?    dir/
X    dir/
?    dir/

Performing status on external item at [dir]
M    file

Performing status on external item at [dir]
?    dir/
?    dir/
?    file
?    file
X    dir/
```

Comment: I myself always keep a zip of backups, independent of any repository.  Very few of them do what I want when it's time to "retro" to the old version (e.g. they give it a new timestamp, instead of the original timestamp)..... Of course, obey your organization's policies and place your code in the repository, for other developers, but by all means keep an independent backup.....

Comment: What is the output of the revert command ? Does it list the reverted files ?

Comment: @LaurentH. I don't believe there was any output.

Comment: show us `svn status` output. Does it have `M` marked items or `?` marked items?

Comment: Read up-to-date documentation. The latest SVNBook version is 1.8 but you refer to 1.5. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.revert.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [svn:externals documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html) there are some commands that will recurse into directories defined by externals. These commands are:

- checkout
- update
- switch
- export
- status

Most of these have an `--ignore-externals` flag letting you avoid updating those.

However, using svn:externals works by creating *independent working copies* below the directory where they are defined. Aside from the small set of commands above, that's *exactly* how the external directories get treated. Specifically in your case, `svn revert` skips right over the external directories, because those are not actually part of this working copy.

Sadly that appears to be one of the remaining rough spots in svn:externals. You'll probably need to change directory into the modified external and revert there as well.

You can probably script this fairly readily.